# mod_rewrite redirect for non-existent URL's

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I've got a an old website that I've taken over. New users essentially get a custom page created for them. It was done in a less than fantastic manner. Currently it actually generates a file named for the slug URL created and symbolically links it to a folder called "/main/". Obviously I want to change this. My plan was simply to have it redirect non-existant folders to "/main/" via .htaccess. Currently this is what my .htaccess looks like:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt|index\.htm)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /main/ [L]
```

However this generates a redirect loop. What am I missing?

## Edit

On that note, I realized I should say I want it to maintain the path that's input. For example if I put http://www.mydomain.com/test_person it should maintain that address, but forward everything to the main folder if that makes sense.

Comment: This is something I really need help with. Any help would be greatly appreciated. I'm banging my head against the wall to figure this out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll want your rule to not rewrite URLs already beginning with main in order to not have it loop, eg:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !^main/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^[^/]+/(.*)$ /main/$1 [L]
```

[L] doesn't really mean what you would think [L] should mean in the context of a .htaccess file.

You should be able to get the original url requested from the REQUEST_URI environment variable, but a common thing to do is to pass the slug to the target as a GET variable.

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/(.*)$ /main/$2?user=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Or pass everything to a single script which interprets the URL and finds the correct content to return:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/(.*)$ /main/index.php?user=$1&path=$2 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: I realized my problem with the looping was somewhere else in the php, but because this is a good answer I'll go ahead and award the bounty.