# How do I block a bot from a specific directory

Tags: apache, .htaccess, webserver, bots

I am getting an insane amount of requests from web crawling bots for files in the /cachecp/ directory on my website (the directory doesn't exist on my server, but I assume it is hacker bots looking for vulnerabilities.) The IP's are all completely different so I can't block IP's.

I get requests such as: 
  mydomain.com/cachecp/helps/wholesale-plus-size-clothing.html
however neither the folder nor the html file exist (or ever have). The html file seems to be totally random and has nothing to do with my offerings.

Can I use htaccess to give a 403 error to any bot trying to access that folder and/or ban that IP from multiple attempts?

Comment: Perhaps **[this](http://perishablepress.com/5g-blacklist-2013/)** will point you in the right direction?

Comment: This may be more suitable http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7323580/mod-rewrite-redirect-for-non-existent-urls

Answer (score 0):

Use this in your robots.txt file

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /cachecp/
```

Bear in mind that robots.txt is a 'gentleman's agreement' and some less scrupulous bots will ignore your rules entirely.