# dot in htaccess gives 500 internal error

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

```
Options +Indexes
# or #
IndexIgnore *
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ profile.php?u=$1 
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$ profile.php?u=$1
```

I want to add dot in rewrite rule so that the username with dot in between them works like rahul.kapoor doesn't works but rahulkapoor works , please help.

Answer (score 2):

Although the dot normally has a special meaning in a regex, it is not a metacharacter when used inside a character class, so in your case you could just use:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_.-]+)/?$ profile.php?u=$1
```

Note that I have made the forward slash at the end optional so you only have to use one line instead of two.

**Edit:** You can also use the word metacharacter to simplify it further:

```
RewriteRule ^([\w.-]+)/?$ profile.php?u=$1
```

Comment: **This** is why I love [so]! Thanks @jeroen, Much better solution!

Comment: My regex looks so ugly next you yours :/

Comment: @Lix Hahaha, it does seem a bit long.

Comment: it's not working , but it's also not showing any 500 internal error ,but it redirects me to 404 page.

Comment: @user2281190 It could be the path to your `profile.php` file. Have you tried an absolute path (relative to the web-server) like `/profile.php`?

Comment: @user2281190 You probably also need to add rules so that existing files do not get rewritten: `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f`, see for example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7323580/mod-rewrite-redirect-for-non-existent-urls

Answer (score 0):

With regular expressions like the ones used in `.htaccess` files, [the dot character has a special meaning](http://www.regular-expressions.info/dot.html). It means "(almost) any character".

If you want to use a "real" dot character, you'll have to escape it with a backslash:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+\.?[a-zA-Z0-9_-]*)/$ profile.php?u=$1
```

What I have done here is changed your regex rule to match:

1. more than one alpha numeric character `[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+`
2. an optional dot character `\.?`
3. more (optional) alpha numeric characters `[a-zA-Z0-9_-]*`

Comment: I use [this tool](http://rubular.com/r/esbORQRjcg) to test simple regular expressions. Perhaps it will be useful for you too :)